# Where I can find list of materials and interact with it?

Tags: materials

Recently I have created a few materials that I don't need anymore. Now, when I'm trying to select material from available materials, I see that old materials. How can I delete them?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett thank you, it works. But the dirty way isn't working - the only change is zero in the name of material. Can you post your comment as answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Strange the "dirty" way isn't working - it's been a traditional way of cleaning up unused things. Maybe they "fixed" the way it works for 3.0+. Anyway, I made it an answer, as requested. Glad some part of it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the icon above your outliner that has a cone and a sphere on it (display mode), you can click and change it to "Orphan data" and clear any unused materials from there.

[image: Orphan]

If you want a really fast, dirty way, save your file, close blender and re-open the file - any unused materials (orphan data) will be cleared. Beware, doing this will clear *all* unused materials (even ones you might want to keep). To make sure an (unused) material is not purged, flag it with a *fake user* by clicking the button underlined below:

[image: Fakeuser]

Answer (score 2):

Blender should automatically remove all unused data-blocks, including materials, when you save and close a file, but sometimes it can be hard to see at a glance what "user" is assigned a certain material—you might think it's not used at all anymore, but actually it's assigned to an object hidden from the viewport etc...

If you're *sure* that you don't need a material anymore and would like to get rid of it permanently, you can switch the display mode of the *Outliner* to *Blender File*, where you are presented with a collapsible list of all data-blocks used in the file. You can expand the *Materials* list, right click on the material in question, and press *Delete*:

[image]